# Spark - "partial" Window function

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

In Spark trying to do "partial" window function.

Giving schema **eventId, impressionTime, campaign, revenue**, I would like to know for each evenId the sum of revenue for the campaign in last 4 days.

At the end, I am only inserting in last 3 days. So I had to load 7 days of data (so the earliest event has the 4 days window) and the problem is that I will calculate also for the events out of my final range.

Small example:
I have data for 7 days (day1, day2, day3, day4, day5, day6, day7 7 is the later) and in the output only days: 7,6,5 are required.

I need the window for every 4 days. So I will load all the days and do window function for them. At the end I will take last only 3 days.

Of course this is very inefficient, since I calculate the window also for
days 4,3...

Is there anyway to do window function on some of the data?

Thanks

Comment: Why won't you filter out data first?

Comment: if you mean adding filter > day 4, because if so, days 3,2,1 will be out of my dataFrame and I won't be able to calculate the revenue for last 4 days for day 4

Answer (score 0):

The [window functions](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.functions$@window(timeColumn:org.apache.spark.sql.Column,windowDuration:String,slideDuration:String,startTime:String):org.apache.spark.sql.Column) do not provide a method by which you can only compute aggregates for a subset of the dates of your input data (days 5, 6 and 7). And as you point out, you can't pre filter because data from days 1 through 4 are necessary to build accurate window aggregates.

If you want to use the Spark window functions then you will have to filter days 1 through 4 after doing the window aggregation.

Another method of computing window aggregates is with simple joins which might be more efficient depending on the size of your data, skew and the length of your window functions. This will not require post-filtering since that is handled with pre-filtering and the join conditions.

```
val df1 = spark.read.table("table1").filter(col("day").isin(Seq(5,6,7):_*))
val df2 = spark.read.table("table1").filter(col("day").isin(Seq(1,2,3,4,5,6,7):_*))

df1.
  join(df2, (df1("key1") === df2("key2")).and(df2("millisecond_ts").between(df1("millisecond_ts") - 1000*60*60*24*4, df1("millisecond_ts"))), "left")
```

Comment: Thanks I am shifting to join as you suggested instead of window. Yet I am facing a skew join problem since the campaign is poorly distributed.
Do you also have a suggestion to overcome this?

Comment: Joining DataFrames with skew is a really difficult problem to solve. The solution depends on the problem and tradeoffs you might be willing to make. This is a pretty good summary of join optimizations: https://github.com/vaquarkhan/vk-wiki-notes/wiki/Apache-Spark-Join-guidelines-and-Performance-tuning